# Angular 2+ swtichMap doesn't work correctly

Tags: angular, http, subject, stackblitz, switchmap

I have a button witch makes a request to the server.
And i'm using the switchMap operator with subject for preventing multiple pending requests.

```
//service
  public getPhotos(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(`url`)
  }
//component
  private $filterSubject: Subject<void> = new Subject();
  public onFetchNewImage(): void {
    this.$filterSubject
      .pipe(
        switchMap(event => {
          return this.photoFetchService.getPhotos();
        })
      )
      .subscribe((photo) => {
        console.log('url', photo);
      })
      this.$filterSubject.next();
  }
```

But, more i click, more i make multiple requests, because my subject.observables array gets bigger each time i make a request
[image: subject log]

here is my code: you can see console.log,
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-delx9m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

Since you added subscription inside click method, each click, add new subsciption to stack.you can avoid this by moving the subscribe code inside ngOnInit.

**Try this:**

**component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.$filterSubject
      .pipe(
        switchMap(event => {
          return this.photoFetchService.getPhotos();
        })
      )
      .subscribe((photo) => {
        console.log('url', photo);
      })
}

 public onFetchNewImage(): void {  
    this.$filterSubject.next();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You keep the `$filterSubject`, and with every click you attach a new pipe with `photoFetchService.getPhotos()`, with a new subscription, to it, while all the old ones are still alive.

So: you click once: subscription no. 1 fires, you click again: new subscription no. 2 fires and the first one *also* fires... And so on. You can fix it for example with the `take` operator

```
    this.$filterSubject
      .pipe(
        switchMap(event => {
          return this.photoFetchService.getPhotos();
        }),
        take(1),
      )
      .subscribe(photo => {
          console.log('url', photo);
      });
```

or rethink the construction.

Comment: How would you change the construction ?

Comment: @ОлегВойтинський see Chellappan வ's answer for one possible solution.